# Get two days data from MySQL table

Tags: mysql, date

I have unix timestamp field in the database.

```
check_in_mktime
-------------
1345639136
1345639146
1345639176
```

How to get the two days data (including today and yesterday) using timestamp.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If there is no checkin in future time, then

```
SELECT * FROM table_name 
WHERE check_in_mktime >= UNIX_TIMESTAMP(CURDATE() - INTERVAL 1 DAY)
```

Answer (score 2):

Try this query -

*(edited)*

```
SELECT * FROM table1
WHERE
  check_in_mktime >= UNIX_TIMESTAMP(CURDATE() - INTERVAL 1 DAY) AND
  check_in_mktime < UNIX_TIMESTAMP(CURDATE() + INTERVAL 1 DAY);
```

Comment: This will only select the yesterday's data plus the data of today's `00:00:00`.

Answer (score 1):

You can do like this:

```
 SELECT * 
 FROM your_table 
  WHERE Date(FROM_UNIXTIME(check_in_mktime)) between date(now() + interval 1 day) and date(now() - interval 1 day)
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to use the following:

- `NOW()`           => current date and time
- `FROM_UNIXTIME()` => converts timestamp to date
- `DATE()` => get date from datetime datatype
- `DATE_SUB()` => subtracts date

Try,

```
  SELECT * 
  FROM  your_table 
  WHERE DATE(FROM_UNIXTIME(check_in_mktime`))     -- converts timestamp to date
                   between DATE(NOW) and                    -- today
                           DATE_SUB(NOW(),INTERVAL 1 DAY)   -- yesterday
```